# The number of monotone Boolean functions

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, boolean-algebras

In the paper "The number of monotone Boolean functions" A. D. Korshunov calculates an asymptotic number of  the number of monotone Boolean functions  ([wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number)):

[image]

However I can not find this paper (even in Russian). Does a proof of this result is expounded somewhere else? Could you give a reference?

Comment: did you check here: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=667&option_lang=eng

Comment: @MoritzFirsching yes, there is only a sketch of proof there

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15433464/pr_kib_38_1981.djvu
(Russian text in djvu)

Comment: @AlexeyMilovanov, this book contains an alternative proof -- Сапоженко А.А. "Проблема Дедекинда и метод граничных функционалов"